# MDX Query: Trying to bring back calculated years

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I have a piece of a report which currently works fine with hard-coded years, I am trying to make them a bit more dynamic so as to show the current year and previous year returns to avoid having to update this every year.  This is a simple thing to do in SQL, but I'm having a much harder time figuring this out in MDX, which I am still learning.  The row in question is the [Date].[Year].&[2013]:[Date].[Year].&[2014].  Here is my current query:

```
SELECT  {   
        [Measures].[Users],
        [Measures].[Sessions]
    } ON COLUMNS,
    (   
        {[User Type].[Description].&[Customer], [User Type].[Description].&[Vendor]},
        [Date].[Year Month].[Year Month],
        [Date].[Month Name].[Month Name],
        [Date].[Year].&[2013]:[Date].[Year].&[2014]
    ) ON ROWS
FROM    [My Cube]
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a range inside a tuple. You first need to create a member.

Put this in before the SELECT clause:

```
WITH Member [Date].[Periods] as Aggregate( [Date].[Year].&[2013]:[Date].[Year].&[2014])
```

and then replace the range in your tuple by `[Date].[Periods]`

Comment: First, thanks for responding.  I tried adding this to the code as you mentioned, however I am now getting this error:  

"Query (1, 6) The 'Date' dimension contains more than one hierarchy, therefore the hierarchy must be explicitly specified."

I'm not quite sure what I would need to do here to fix this.

Comment: You need to specify one of the hierarchies in the definition of the calculated member.